# How to write a PowerShell script to compare the input csv file with the output from SQL Server query and trigger a mail?

Tags: sql-server, powershell, if-statement, compare

[Master input csv file][1]][1]
[![enter image description here][2]][2]
[Sql query result which can have more no of users][1]

[![enter image description here][3]][3]

### In the below script, I have to compare the output with an input csv file, and if the values don't match, then trigger a mail. If the values are equal, then no mail should be triggered.

```
  param(
    $emailFrom = 'Reporting.Services@accenture.com',
    $emailTo = @("aditi.m.singh@accenture.com","s.ab.balakrishnan@accenture.com","rajeshbabu.ks@accenture.com"),
    $emailSubject = 'Sending the Attachment',
    $smtp = 'AMRINT.SMTP.ACCENTURE.COM',
    $Server = (Import-Csv -Path "D:\Scripts\input.csv").ComputerName ,
    $Adgroup = (Import-Csv -Path "D:\Scripts\inputAdGroup.csv").UserName ,
    $SQLDBName = 'ReportServer',
    $SQLQuery = @"
        SELECT Distinct
            RL.RoleName,
            USR.UserName
        FROM  
            Catalog C
            INNER JOIN Policies PL 
                    ON C.PolicyID = PL.PolicyID
            INNER JOIN PolicyUserRole PUR
                    ON PUR.PolicyID = PL.PolicyID
            INNER JOIN Users USR
                    ON PUR.UserID = USR.UserID
            INNER JOIN dbo.Roles RL
                    ON RL.RoleID = PUR.RoleID    
            WHERE RoleName = 'Content Manager' 
            ORDER BY USR.UserName    
"@
)

$emailSent =  if ($SQLQuery -eq $AdGroup) {write-host "there are no changes"} else
     {'@("aditi.m.singh@accenture.com","s.ab.balakrishnan@accenture.com","rajeshbabu.ks@accenture.com")'}

# This code connects to the SQL server and retrieves the data    
$SQLConnection = New-Object System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection    
$SqlConnection.ConnectionString = "Server = $Server; Database = $SQLDBName; Integrated Security=true;"    
$SqlCmd = New-Object System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand    
$SqlCmd.CommandText = $SqlQuery    
$SqlCmd.Connection = $SqlConnection    
$SqlAdapter = New-Object System.Data.SqlClient.SqlDataAdapter    
$SqlAdapter.SelectCommand = $SqlCmd    
$DataSet = New-Object System.Data.DataSet    
$SqlAdapter.Fill($DataSet)    
$SqlConnection.Close()               
$Style = "
<style>
    TABLE{border-width: 1px;border-style: solid;border-color: black;border-collapse: collapse;}
    TH{border-width: 1px;padding: 3px;border-style: solid;border-color: black;}
    TD{border-width: 1px;padding: 3px;border-style: solid;border-color: black;}
</style>
"
$data = $DataSet.Tables[0]
$html = $data `
    | Select-Object -Property RoleName, UserName `
    |  ConvertTo-HTML -head $Style  `
            | Out-String

Send-MailMessage `
    -From $emailFrom `
    -To $emailTo `
    -Subject $emailSubject `
    -BodyAsHtml $html `
    -SmtpServer $smtp
```

Comment: One thing I noticed at first glance: you are not setting a value for the `-Body` parameter, instead you set the $html to the **boolean** `-BodyAsHtml` switch.. Change that to `-Body  $html` and `-BodyAsHtml`. Also, I'd recommend using [Splatting](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_splatting), so you can get rid of thoze nasty backticks for cmdlets that need a lot of parameters. [2} Your question is about comparing stuff to a CSV. Where is the code for that? Please add an example of the CSV.

Comment: Why not read the CSV in a, say, temp table and use it to filter results?

Comment: @Theo please give your insights on how to trigger a mail only if the input cvs file and the sql query output doesnt match and the mail should have those mismatched values.

Comment: I cannot, because you did not edit your question and show us what the result of the `$SQLQuery` is, or what the CSV file looks like. No way to compare two unknown data sources.. BTW. Please use the [edit](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/61609653/edit) link underneath your question to add more information. In comments it becomes unreadable.

Comment: @Theo i have shared the screenshot for the sql query output and the master input csv file. The scenario is if both have same user names then the mail should not get triggerd and if ithe output is not matching with the master file then those user name should be send in the mail with its role.

Comment: @Theo i have added the edited the script and added the scripts for comparing input csv file and sql query result.